# Does the onPostExecute runs only once no matter how many params are in the execute?

Tags: android

When executing an `AsyncTask` with more than one argument values , say :

```
new myAsyncTask().execute(paramValue1 , paramValue2);
```

Does the `onPostExecute` run for each ending of execution for each param value or for the entire whole set of params ?

Comment: it has nothing do with params. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: it runs whenever `doInBackground` ends

Comment: You are probably confused. The number of times onPostExecute() runs has nothing to do with paramters.

Comment: `onPostExecute` execution depends on your request of class execution. It has nothing to do with how many parameters you pass. It execute at the end of AsyncRequest. Number of Execution Request You send same number of time it will execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once only, you also get all the params at once in the doInBackground and not in multiple calls.